# Conditionally splitting a HTML list in two

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to split a list into depending on the number of elements in the array. If the number of ingredients in the array is greater than 6, then I want the list to split in two. Can't figure out how I would go about doing this! I know there is a CSS property which allows you to split a list into two but there was a formatting issue when doing it this way and I only want to split the list if it reaches the bottom of the container (which is 6 items).

Here is the relevant html code:

```
<ul class="Ingredients-list">
        <li class="Ingredients-list-item"
        *ngFor="let Ingredient of selectedRecipe.ingredients">
        {{ Ingredient.name }} - {{ Ingredient.amount }}
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is the relevant CSS code:

```
 .Ingredients-list-item {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    left: 10px;
    top: 15px;
    font-size: 80%;
    /* columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2; */
}
```

Here is the Component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipeservice } from '../recipes/recipes.service'
import { Recipe } from '../recipes/recipes.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-view',
  templateUrl: './recipe-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-view.component.css'],
})
export class RecipeViewComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedRecipe: Recipe;

  constructor(private recipeService: Recipeservice) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recipeService.RecipeSelected.subscribe(
      (recipe: Recipe) => {
        this.selectedRecipe = recipe;
        console.log(this.selectedRecipe);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the CSS columns on the `ul` tag instead of the `li` tag. Below is a working example. Hope this is relevant to your problem!

Also we need to add a class when list is greater than 6.

```
<ul class="Ingredients-list" [ngClass]="{'greater': recipes.length > 5}">
    <li class="Ingredients-list-item" *ngFor="let Ingredient of recipes">
        {{ Ingredient.name }} - {{ Ingredient.amount }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS will be as follows:

```
 .Ingredients-list-item {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 80%;
}
 .Ingredients-list.greater{  
  columns: 2;
  height:140px;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

<kbd>**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpven1?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**</kbd>

Comment: This is great thank you! The only problem I have now is that the formatting of the two lists isn't quite right. The right hand list puts the first item in the list higher than the first item of the left hand list so it looks strange!

Comment: @JohnDev Please adjust the css alone, I think the top and left position css will mess up the alignment, you can remove them